# PhpStorm + Xdebug - fatal error when listening, otherwise script runs fine

Tags: magento, phpstorm, xdebug

Edit: I thought this had at least something do with the module I was creating. But even when I switch back to my master branch I have the same problem.

Why would listening for an Xdebug connection here on my Windows machine affect the code execution on the remote machine such that it would generate fatal errors? I don't think I changed anything about my Xdebug setup since yesterday, when it worked. Perhaps I changed some PhpStorm setting that affects PHP execution on the remote server. Is that possible?

Here is my local php.ini's Xdebug section. I have `xdebug.remote_host` set to `localhost` because I am connecting with an SSH tunnel. The connection is certainly working, though, that's not the problem.

[image: Php.ini Xdebug Settings]

I'm also seeing Apache redirect errors. Is my xdebug connection somehow causing these redirects?

```
[Tue Feb 09 18:40:01.465356 2016] [core:error] [pid 31043] [client 127.0.0.1:53428] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

End Edit.

2nd Edit:

I tried pulled my git repo to a new server, installed a copy of the db, and connected with the same PhpStorm configuration and ran into the same problem. Another PhpStorm project running on that server worked perfectly, so I was hopeful that would solve it. But it seems that the issue is indeed somewhere on my local machine.

So I created a new PhpStorm project, did a fresh clone from github, entered in all the myriad Server and Debug settings I could think of. So, fresh files, fresh server, fresh PhpStorm project and... it works! Sort of.

There is still a very odd issue that is, I think, related to the error from before. I set a breakpoint that should only have been hit once during a request, and yet it was hit 4 times, and PhpStorm gave me a notice that "Debug session was finished without being paused" afterwards, which suggests at least one more request went through without hitting that particular breakpoint.

I still don't know the exact cause of the fatal errors on the other PhpStorm installation, either.

End 2nd Edit.

Is there any explanation for PhpStorm and/or Xdebug changing the functionality of a PHP script?

I have Xdebug 2.3.2 and PHP 5.5.20 running on a remote CentOS machine, debugging a Magento 1.7 store, using the Magicento plugin. There is definitely some connection between the issue and the module I am trying to create and mangling the XML for. But to me that does not explain why the code would work differently when I'm debugging it.

Everything seemed to be working correctly yesterday and I was able to connect to the remote debugging session and step through the code line by line. *And I can still do that today*, but now the script throws fatal errors whenever I listen for debug connections, and runs fine when I don't. How can the observer affect the observed? This isn't quantum physics!

For example, I just tried to load the admin, and found this in my `error_log`.

```
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isAvailable() on a non-object in /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php on line 572
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/butkus/public_html/index.php:0
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   2. Mage::run($code = *uninitialized*, $type = *uninitialized*, $options = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/index.php:86
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run($params = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/Mage.php:683
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match($request = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch($action = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:254
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   7. Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:419
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   8. Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout($ids = *uninitialized*, $generateBlocks = *uninitialized*, $generateXml = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php:40
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP   9. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout($handles = *uninitialized*, $generateBlocks = *uninitialized*, $generateXml = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php:275
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  10. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:269
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  11. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks($parent = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:344
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  12. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks($parent = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:210
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  13. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock($node = *uninitialized*, $parent = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:205
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  14. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock($block = *uninitialized*, $blockName = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:239
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  15. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock($type = *uninitialized*, $name = *uninitialized*, $attributes = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:472
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  16. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout($layout = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:456
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  17. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:238
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  18. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock($type = *uninitialized*, $name = *uninitialized*, $attributes = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php:75
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  19. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout($layout = *uninitialized*) /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:456
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  20. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Grids->_prepareLayout() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:238
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  21. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Grids.php:64
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  22. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:862
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  23. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php:632
[10-Feb-2016 00:39:01 UTC] PHP  24. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareMassactionBlock() /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php:625
[10-Feb-2016 00:44:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isAvailable() on a non-object in /home/butkus/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php on line 572
[10-Feb-2016 00:44:11 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[10-Feb-2016 00:44:11 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/butkus/public_html/index.php:0
@
"error_log" 52L, 9168C                                                                                                   1,1           Top
```

I was able to put a break point in the line before the fatal error and view the application state.

The mysteriously malformed array, `$this->children` has only one element,
with key `mymessedupmodule` and value object `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction` which has a property `_alias = 'mymessedupmodule`. Somehow, my module is taking over everything else. But this doesn't seem to happen when I turn off PhpStorm listening for debug connection. How can I debug my application if it behaves differently when it's being debugged?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question "Is there any explanation for PhpStorm and/or Xdebug changing the functionality of a PHP script?" yes for example you could have errors because of the xdebug nesting level in that case you could add xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200, I am not sure this has anything to do with your problem but it sounds like you are setting some variables in the watcher area, please try to remove everything in watcher and run again

Comment: Hi laurent. I did add a watch yesterday. I deleted all watches but the issue still occurs. I also have a lot of breakpoints, although most aren't getting hit anyway. Still, should I delete them too?
By the way, I got the debugging to work again, kind of, by starting a whole new PhpStorm project based on the same files (freshly downloaded from Github). But it is still acting weird, stopping 4 times at a breakpoint that should only occur once per request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the actual IP address of your local computer.  I was getting this error too, using `xdebug.remote_host = localhost`. When I changed it to 192.168.5.116 it immediately accepted the connection on my local machine.  I'm using xdebug + phpstorm.